# How to obtain the computer's name on macOS?

Tags: macos, delphi, pascal

How does one get the name of the computer on macOS with Delphi?

I am trying to automatically get and display the computer's name in my application but cannot seem to get it working on macOS. I have it working on Windows but can not get it working on macOS.

Comment: Maybe this lib contains what you need: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri

Comment: I know noting about macOS (have never used an Apple product all my life!) but surely it offers some simple API function for obtaining the computer name, like the Win32 [GetComputerName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamea).

Answer (score 1):

This code will retrieve the computer name on macOS:

```
uses
  Macapi.Foundation, Macapi.Helpers;

function GetComputerName: string;
begin
  Result := NSStrToStr(TNSHost.Wrap(TNSHost.OCClass.currentHost).localizedName);  
end;
```

If you're after cross-platform way of doing it, refer to the `GetDeviceName` method (named that way since it also deals with mobile devices), here:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/master/Core/DW.OSDevice.pas

Answer (score 0):

this lib support WIN and linux,  it may work with macOS  ...

https://github.com/RRUZ/tsmbios

Answer (score 0):

use gethostname() in the Posix.UniStd unit

Comment: [Code example as picture with minor typos](https://www.devpage.de/blog/firemonkey-Teil3.htm).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).